# Bean Validation: multiple validators on field

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Suppose there is a bean like this:

```
public class Test {

   @NotBlank
   @Size(max=200)
   @Pattern(regexp="(\\d|\\+|-|\\?)*")
   private String field;

   //getters and setters
}
```

It is required to display all the error messages. So if both validators failed it is necessary to get both messages.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> It is required to display all the error messages. So if both validators failed it is necessary to get both messages.

That is the default behavior. `Validator.validate` will return a set of `ConstraintViolation` instances. One for each failing constraint. Only if groups or group sequences are involved there might not be all constraints evaluated.

Have you actually tried this and found an actual problem?